# Git restore branch that was deleted both locally and on the server

Tags: git, github

I am trying to restore a branch that was deleted about a week ago from the remote server. Since that time I completely blew away my local repo for that project so there is no local version of that branch either. I tried "git fsck" but didn't see anything related to my branch there.

Comment: Have you run `git gc` recently? (If not, _don't run it_)

Comment: On the server? Have no idea if they ran it or not though I understand that if they did I'm done :(

Comment: I meant locally. Could you check `git reflog`? https://confluence.atlassian.com/bbkb/how-to-restore-a-deleted-branch-765757540.html

Comment: Ideally try to remember the commit message, or the commit hash, etc.

Comment: As I mentioned earlier I completely blew away my local repo folder

Comment: Can you ssh into the remote server and check there?

Comment: I can't but our server admin can. Do you know what command they need to use?

Comment: `git reflog`, but they'd need to know what they're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Find the sha by a `git reflog` (the last commit on the branch) and do `git checkout -b <branch> <sha>` on a command line prompt.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be some local repo somewhere that hasn't done a `git fetch --prune`, that'd still be tracking the last-known tip.

But failing that, since the branch was deleted on the server "about a week ago", the factory-default expiry on unreferenced objects hasn't passed so auto-gc shouldn't have cleaned it out yet.  ssh in to that repo, do

```
git fsck --lost-found --connectivity-only
```

and `git show` or maybe e.g. `git log --online --graph --decorate master..$id` the id's in the `lost-found/commits` directory to see if any of them look good. Any that do, you can make a new branch tip for them, if the commit's still in the repo its history's still there too.

If you don't want to operate on a live server you can just rsync or tar or whatever the repo itself, the whole thing, to wherever you want, then spelunk at leisure. You might have to remove any stray `find -name \*.lock` files if somebody was pushing during the copy, or play with the configs if there are any hardwired paths configured going outside the repo itself but that's unusual.